# Compiler Maven with IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a problem with Maven and IntelliJ.
I have correctly informed the Maven and Java path, in a terminal when I type mvn --version I have the version of jdk 14 of filled in.
But when I want to do a clean mvn install in intelliJ, I have this error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins: maven-compiler-plugin: 3.8.1: compile (default-compile) on project springboot-restserverapi: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 14 -> [Help 1]
```

I do not understand, in the Maven configuration of IntelliJ I have correctly entered the correct Maven path, my PATHs are correct, I do not see or it is blocking.

In my pom.xml I have well informed:

```
<maven.compiler.source> 14 </maven.compiler.source> 
<maven.compiler.target> 14 </maven.compiler.target>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure if the whitespaces matter. Try to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You have set your `%JAVA_HOME` to JDK 14. Install JDK 14 and make sure your %JAVA_HOME points to that.

`invalid target release: 14`

The target release refers to the JDK version.

To set `JAVA_HOME`, do the following:

1. Right click `My Computer` and select `Properties`.
2. On the `Advanced` tab, select `Environment Variables`, and then edit `JAVA_HOME` to point to where the JDK software is located, for example, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_02`.

Comment: To set the variable `JAVA_HOME` on Linux is even easier. I suppose you already did it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the 14 JDK for the Maven in the IDE:

- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | **JDK for importer**
- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | **JRE**